# In a SQLite database is it better to use tirggers to handle cascading table changes, or is it better to do it programmatically?

Tags: triggers, sqlite, system.data.sqlite, data-integrity

**Background**

I have a couple of projects that use a SQLite DB for data. The data stored in the databases are obviously stored across several tables, linked by key/foreign key values.

The thing is that in these databases, if something changes to one record I have to update several other tables. The best example off the top of my head is deleting a record. I have to make sure all other records related to the one being deleted are deleted as well. Now, this example can be solved using key/foreign key values, I believe, but what about more complicated updates?

Now I'm no pro DB admin, but I know that there needs to be data integrity in the DB or things get ugly.

**The Question**

So, my question. I know that I have greater control when updating related tables programmatically, but at the cost of human error and time. I may miss something or not implement the tables updates correctly and it takes a lot longer to code in the updates. On the other hand, I can put in triggers and let the DB handle the updates to other tables, but I then lose a lot of control.

So, which one is better? Is each better in different situations?

Comment: Didn't you consider using `ON DELETE CASCADE` in your FK definitions? Triggers, when implemented correctly, allows you to have a DB which is always consistent. But these are not quite easy to implement correctly, and triggers usually have little elbow room to operate. I'd try `ON DELETE` and trigger approach first if the cascading requirements are simple and clear.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I know the example I gave can be solved with k/fk's, but I'm wondering about more complex table updates, like if a "Name" column (which is not a key) changes and has to change elsewhere. Things that are not related to keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the other hand, I can put in
>   triggers and let the DB handle the
>   updates to other tables, but I then
>   lose a lot of control.

What control do you think you're losing? If data integrity requires that "such-and-such an update *here* requires additional updates *there* and *there*", you're not losing control by coding that in a trigger. You're centralizing control, and delegating it to the dbms, which is the only piece of software that can guarantee every application follows those requirements.

> I know that I have greater control
>   when updating related tables
>   programmatically, but at the cost of
>   human error and time. I may miss
>   something or not implement the tables
>   updates correctly and it takes a lot
>   longer to code in the updates.

You're thinking like a programmer, not a database designer. (That's an observation, not a criticism.) Don't think, "I might miss something". That way of thinking really misses the mark.

Instead, when you're tempted to delegate data integrity to application code, think "Every programmer and every new or changed application that hits this database from now until the end of time has to get it perfectly right."

Now, honestly, does that *really* sound like a good idea to you?

(The last Fortune 500 company I worked in had programs written in at least two dozen different languages hitting their OLTP database.)

Comment: +1 "Every programmer and every new or changed application that hits this database from now until the end of time has to get it perfectly right."